# Negate field value to set control visiblity

Tags: asp.net, controls, visible, databound

I have a control with the visible property set to the value of a boolean field. However, I want the visiblity to be the opposite of the boolean field. How do I do this?

This code shows the visible property set to the value of the field. I want to negate that value.

```
<span runat="server" id="toMonthYear" visible='<%#Eval("isAttending")%>'>
     <%#Eval("toMonthName")%> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply cast it to `bool` and use the [negation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ([`NOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx) in VB.NET).

```
Visible='<%# !(bool)Eval("isAttending") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<span runat="server" id="toMonthYear" visible='<%#(!Boolean.Parse(Eval("isAttending"))%>'>
```